# PySide2 QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout which already has a layout

Tags: python, pyside2, qlayout

I need help figuring this error out.  I set the Form using a grid layout and this error comes up when i run it.  I don't get the error if I remove the form grid layout.  Thanks

QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "Form", which already has a layout.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

from ui_mainWindow import Ui_Form

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form): 


    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit( ret )
```

---

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, -1))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, -1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i fix the error because i want to use the form grid layout.

Comment: @mark change `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):` to `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):`

Comment: @eyllanesc Wow Thanks alot..it worked